# Generating 3 combinations in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-2.x, combinatorics

I have been experimenting around with generating all the n-combinations of an array. This code quickly generates all \$\text{k-combinations}\$ of a given array. I am testing my own implementation because of some restrictions in coding competitions (also, knowing the basics never hurts).

```
"""
Generates 3-combinations of an array.

A B C D E F G H
^ ^ ^
i j k

A B C D E F G H
^ ^   ^
i j   k

A B C D E F G H
^   ^   ^
i   j   k
"""
from itertools import combinations
import time

def combinations_3(ary):
    l = len(ary)
    for i in xrange(l-2):
        for j in xrange(i+1, l-1):
            for k in xrange(j+1, l):
                yield (ary[i], ary[j], ary[k])


start = time.time()      
for combination in combinations_3([1, 2, 3, 4]):
    print combination
print time.time() - start

print("===========Library Implementation============")
start = time.time()
for combination in combinations([1, 2, 3, 4], 3):
    print combination
print time.time() -start
```

#### Output

```
(1, 2, 3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(1, 2, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(1, 3, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(2, 3, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0.00043797492981                                                                                                                                                                                                           
===========Library Implementation============                                                                                                                                                                              
(1, 2, 3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(1, 2, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(1, 3, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
(2, 3, 4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
6.19888305664e-05
```

It seems that my implementation is a lot slower than the library code. How can I improve performance of my code.

Comment: Python is open source; have you considered looking at the library [code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c) to see what the differences are (it's written in C, for a start)?

Comment: Your only hope to make it faster is to write it in C, like stdlib, or Cythonize your code.

Comment: @Davidmh, fine, Then I think this code is fine as a quick hard coded way to write combinations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use `timeit` module with similar setup:

*run.py*

```
from itertools import combinations


def combinations_3(ary):
    l = len(ary)
    for i in xrange(l-2):
        for j in xrange(i+1, l-1):
            for k in xrange(j+1, l):
                yield (ary[i], ary[j], ary[k])


def _test(generator):
    for combination in generator:
        #: To meger time of sequence generation we should ommit IO operations.
        pass


def test_lib(lenght=10000):
    _test(combinations(list(range(1, lenght)), 3))


def test_self_written(lenght=10000):
    _test(combinations_3(list(range(1, lenght))))
```

*test.py*

```
import timeit

#: Print title
print('                library time   self written time')

#: Counter of sequence number.
for i in list(range(10, 100, 10)):
    #: Meger execution time for self written combinations implementation.
    self_written = timeit.Timer(
        #: Tested expression.
        'test_lib({})'.format(i),
        #: Test setup, here we just import tested function.
        'from run import test_self_written as test_lib'
    ).timeit(1000)  #: And here we just set number of testing iterations.

    lib = timeit.Timer(
        'test_lib({})'.format(i),
        'from run import test_lib'
    ).timeit(1000)

    #: Print output in format "<number of elements>: library time, self written time"
    print('{:03} elements: {:10.6f}     {:10.6f}'.format(i, lib, self_written))
```

And here is my output:

```
$ python2 test.py 
                library time   self written time
010 elements:   0.007060       0.030495
020 elements:   0.058317       0.239376
030 elements:   0.211884       0.817189
040 elements:   0.522477       1.903142
050 elements:   1.047018       3.803112
060 elements:   1.969069       6.590189
070 elements:   2.960615      10.500072
080 elements:   4.468489      15.176092
090 elements:   6.402755      21.669669
$ python3 test.py 
                library time   self written time
010 elements:   0.009168       0.038298
020 elements:   0.058049       0.285885
030 elements:   0.208938       1.031432
040 elements:   0.523407       2.450311
050 elements:   1.048463       4.796328
060 elements:   1.828277       7.832434
070 elements:   2.970929      13.067557
080 elements:   4.481792      18.496334
090 elements:   6.353836      26.277946
$ pypy test.py 
                library time   self written time
010 elements:   0.011924       0.040272
020 elements:   0.056972       0.046638
030 elements:   0.185858       0.083793
040 elements:   0.456202       0.188640
050 elements:   0.913935       0.338211
060 elements:   1.588666       0.542124
070 elements:   2.537772       0.846942
080 elements:   3.816353       1.232982
090 elements:   5.471375       1.707760
```

And python versions

```
$ python2 -V && python3 -V && pypy -V
Python 2.7.6
Python 3.4.3
[PyPy 2.2.1 with GCC 4.8.2]
```

As you can see, `pypy` is much faster than `cpython` implementation.

Actually, if you are using cpython you do not really want to reinvent standard library functions because they are pretty nice optimized by c compiler and you code will be interpreted instead of compiling. In case of pypy you probably want to make some research, because JIT interpreter have a lot of different corner cases.

Comment: **You do not really want to reinvent standard library functions because they are pretty nice optimized by c compiler** -> Well said

Comment: @JaDogg, reinventing and understanding is quite different things I think. In that manner you shouldn't write any sorting algorithm at all, right? because they are already implemented out there.

Comment: In fact these approach are quite useful when your coding environment doesn't allow external libraries or your use case is quite restricted.

Comment: I'd like to join discussion with title "std:: or not std::" but we are talking about `python`, not `c++`.

Comment: @CodeYogi `090 elements:   6.353836      26.277946` is best proof of my words. But it is only for `cpython` not `pypy`.

Comment: @CodeYogi reinventing is great for understanding, but when you said you're slow compared to the std lib, you're comparing apples to oranges. The standard library is full of optimizations.

Comment: I never wanted to emphasize on it. My bad if that point got highlighted. I wanted if I can improve performance any further.

Comment: @CodeYogi If you use the Python version of [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), then you can see that, your function is faster. For me yours was more than 10 times faster...

Answer (score 4):

I was able to shave off 20 % of time in outoftime's test by avoiding the indexed lookups in `(ary[i], ary[j], ary[k])` and doing this instead:

```
def combinations_3(ary):
    enumerated = list(enumerate(ary))
    for i, x in enumerated[:-2]:
        for j, y in enumerated[i+1:-1]:
            for z in ary[j+1:]:
                yield (x, y, z)
```

Precomputing the slice of the innermost loop for each `j` takes another 10 % off:

```
def combinations_3(ary):
    enumerated = [(i, value, ary[i+1:]) for i, value in enumerate(ary)]
    for i, x, _ in enumerated[:-2]:
        for _, y, tail in enumerated[i+1:-1]:
            for z in tail:
                yield (x, y, z)
```

It is worth noting that the first version requires O(n) additional space for the list slices, and the second version ups the requirement to O(n<sup>2</sup>), where n is the size of `ary`.

Comment: Do these optimizations affects the Big-O complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: @CodeYogi Space complexity increases from O(1) to O(n) and to O(n^2) in the second version. Time complexity remains O(n^3).